# axislabel values are not all shown

Tags: c#, charts

I have a small problem. In my chart not all the axislabels are shown, just a few. Just so you can see, here's what I'm refering
[image]

The code that I'm using is this :

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, values> value1 in chartStats)
        {

            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
            dp.AxisLabel = value1.Key;

            dp.YValues = new double[] { value1.Value.percent };

            chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);


            DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint();
            dp1.YValues = new double[] { (double)value1.Value.angleSumHits };
            chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(dp1);



        }
```

I've tried changing the size of the chart but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

But if you have too many datapoints the labels can overlap

Comment: sorry for being late.i'll post a answer to your question now

Answer (score 0):

so for me volkan answer worked. the code part is this :

```
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, values> value1 in chartStats)
        {

            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
            dp.AxisLabel = value1.Key;

            dp.YValues = new double[] { value1.Value.percent };

            chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint();
            //dp1.AxisLabel = "a";
            dp1.YValues = new double[] { (double)value1.Value.angleSumHits };
            chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(dp1);

           }
```

[image]